# Set height of individual items recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am creating an app that allows users to upload videos. I want the videos to all have the same height but currently they show up according to their actual height and width in the database.

I checked almost 10 questions on here but none were able to solve my problem. Can someone help me ?

fragment_profile.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragment.ProfileFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:background="#ECEFF1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:4"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ProfileFragment.Java:

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
[RecyclerView][1]LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3) {

@Override
        public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
            // force size of viewHolder here, this will override layout_height and layout_width from xml
            //lp.height = (int) ( getHeight() * 0.75);
            //lp.width = (int) (getWidth() * 0.75);
            return true;
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    postList = new ArrayList<>();
    myFotoAdapter = new MyFotoAdapter(getContext(), postList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myFotoAdapter);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerI
```

[RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PNje.png)

Comment: Post the recyclerview item layout.

Comment: @DarShan just updated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.